# Java awt.Robot: send key with position for eg. right shift or right ctrl

Tags: java, keyboard, virtual, awtrobot

I want to use the `java.awt.Robot` class to implement a virtual keyboard. I am wondering if there is a way to send the keycode WITH the key location (left or right) using the `keyPress(int)` method. If you add a `KeyListener` to an awt Element, a `KeyEvent` triggered by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> has an information if it was the left or right button.

The Docs tells:

> Key codes that have more than one physical key associated with them (e.g. `KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT` could mean either the left or right shift key) will map to the left key".

But is there really no way to send a <kbd>right shift</kbd> pressed? Some applications (eg. VirtualBox) need those right buttons (sure, you might configure those applications, but thats no option for a virtual keyboard).

So... is there a way to do this with the `Robot` class?
Is there an alternative way to send more specific key events in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching I currently think that `java.awt.Robot` might be not the right choice. There are known problems sending special keys like german umlauts that has no key code assigend in the jvm.

So I answer this question myself with "There is no way to do it with the `Robot` class".

Comment: I am not sure if you really want to know it (ugly, dirty, much code), but ^^
I know use Synergy (http://synergy-foss.org/). The synergy client connects to my java instance. The java instance then sends synergy data packets. I inspected the synergy traffic with wireshark because I found no protocol specs... The main problem is that I have to map EVERY key or mouse event to a synergy event (found no automatic solution)... and there are many keys on a keyboard ;)

Still found no Java-based solution.